# how to map log data fields to base model in mongodb in useing mongo appender in log4j2.xml

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql, log4j2, rollingfileappender

i have a constant data model for a collection in mongo db and now i want map log data to my collection model.
my collection:

```
@Document(collection = "LOG")public class LogCollection {
@Field("LOG_LEVEL")
private String logLevel;}
```

mongo appender:

```
 <Appenders>
<NoSql name="MongoDbAppender">
  <MongoDb4 connection="mongodb://log4jUser:12345678@localhost:${sys:MongoDBTestPort:-27017}/testDb.testCollection" />
</NoSql>
```

now i want same thing:

```
  <Field name="LOG_LEVEL" pattern="%level"/>
```

in java with log4j2 and mongodb4